# Prove that if $G$ is a simple graph on n vertices such that $\delta(G) \geq \lfloor n/2\rfloor$, then $G$ is connected.

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

I need to prove that if G is a simple graph on n vertices such that $\delta(G) \ge \lfloor n/2\rfloor$, then $G$ is connected (Where $\delta(G)$ represents the minumum degrees in $G$).

To prove this I want to show that for every vertex $u,v \in V(G)$ (where V represents the vertex set of our graph $G$) there exists a $u,v$-path in $G$.

So far I have:

Let $u,v \in V(G)$. If $u$ and $v$ are adjacent, there exists a path from $u$ to $v$ consisting of a single edge.

How do I prove this for greater lengths? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What if $\delta(G) = 0 \le \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$?

Comment: If you want $G$ be connected, $\delta(G)$ should be larger than something

Comment: Hint: if $G$ is not connected, then one of the connected components must have $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ or fewer vertices.

Comment: Are you sure the problem says $\delta(G)\le\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ not $\delta(G)\ge\lfloor n/2\rfloor$?